# Combine three arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I am looking for a more efficient way of combining these three arrays. Two data arrays and a "cross" array that connects the two arrays.

#### 3 Arrays

```
var drives = [
    {"drivesId": "rwd", "name": "RWD"},
    {"drivesId": "fwd", "name": "FWD"},
    {"drivesId": "awd", "name": "AWD"}
]


var cars = [
    {"carId": "civic", "name": "Civic"},
    {"carId": "wrx", "name": "WRX"},
    {"carId": "mustang", "name": "Mustang"},
    {"carId": "focus", "name": "Focus"},
]

var drivesXcars = [
    {"drivesXcars": "uid1", "carId": "civic", "drivesId": "fwd"},
    {"drivesXcars": "uid2", "carId": "wrx", "drivesId": "awd"},
    {"drivesXcars": "uid3", "carId": "mustang", "drivesId": "rwd"},
    {"drivesXcars": "uid4", "carId": "focus", "drivesId": "fwd"},
]
```

I would like them to be combined into one array that looks like this:

```
var carsComplete = [
    {"drivesId": "fwd", "driveName": "FWD", "cars": [
        {"carId": "civic", "name": "Civic"},
        {"carId": "focus", "name": "Focus"}
    ]},
    {"drivesId": "rwd", "driveName": "RWD", "cars": [
        {"carId": "mustang", "name": "Mustang"}
    ]},
    {"drivesId": "awd", "driveName": "AWD", "cars": [
        {"carId": "wrx", "name": "WRX"}
    ]},
]
```

Yeah, I could do this the standard for loop way but these arrays get bigger and the standard "brute force" way isn't good enough for me.

I was hoping someone would know of a more efficient way of doing this using AngularJS and/or lodash.

Comment: you don't need much brute force, depending on how you code it.  i would first turn drives and cars into an object keyed by the interesting prop, then simply iterate drivesXcars and mash them together like `obCars[x.carId]`, instead of some silly/slow `indexOf()` madness...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily achieved in plain JavaScript:

```
const carsComplete = drives.map(x => ({
  drivesId: x.drivesId,
  driveName: x.name,
  cars: drivesXcars
    // Only the cars which belong to this person.
    .filter(n => n.drivesId === x.drivesId) 
    // Get the car by id.
    .map(n => cars.find(m => m.carId === n.carId))
}))
```

See [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xaqomi/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var drivesXcarsGroup = _.groupBy(drivesXcars, "drivesId");
var carsComplete = drives.map(function(driver){
                            return {
                                "drivesId": driver.drivesId,
                                "driveName": driver.name,
                                "cars": drivesXcarsGroup[driver.name.toLowerCase()]
                               }
                           });
```